# function returning pointer to object in a 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

i have a 2d array of struct _tile.
i want a function returning a tile within it.

here is code that i use to generate 2d array of tiles.as i am going to do some path finding and dungeon work.

the function get tile at

```
enum{normalfloor,door};
```

tile structure.

```
     struct _tile{
int type;
bool isSet; 
int x,y;
_tile *camefrom;
int index;  
bool changeTo(int a){
    if(!isSet){
        type = a;
        isSet = 1;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}   
};
```

dungeon map creation code:

```
int Mw,Mh;
_tile **tile;
void create(int w = 30,int h = 30){
    Mw=w,Mh=h;      
    tile = new _tile *[w];
    for(int a=0,_index=0;a<w;a++){
        tile[a] = new _tile[h];
        for(int b=0;b<h;b++,_index++){
            _tile *C = &tile[a][b];
            C->type = normalfloor;
            //1) Start with a rectangular grid, x units wide and y units tall. Mark each cell in the grid unvisited.                
            C->isSet = 0;
            C->x = a;               
            C->y = b;
            C->index = _index;              
        }           
    }
}
```

i want a function to return a tile at given index.
but for some reason this does not work.

```
_tile getTileAt(int index){
    int z[2];
    int rem = index/Mh;
    int X = index-(rem*Mh);
    int Y = index - X;
    return *tile[X][Y];
}
```

when i use this

```
            _tile *a; 
        a = getTileAt(10);
        a->changeTo(door);// here program crashes.
```

i have been searching over net.but got no satisfactory results.

Comment: Is this really how you format your code?

Comment: "this does not work" Debug it. What happens? What is the result you get? What is the result you expected? Apply critical thinking. Write out the steps on paper and figure out where it diverges. SO is not a helpdesk.

Comment: What exactly is not working? How does the return value of `getTileAt` differ from the expected value?

Comment: it does not return anything.in other words my program gives error of 3221225477.and project1.exe has stopped working.where i am expecting a pointer to the specific element in the array,my program crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed up the remainder computation and computation for `X`. Try this:

```
_tile getTileAt(int index){
    int X = index/Mh;
    int Y = index-(X*Mh);
    return *tile[X][Y];
}
```

You can be even simpler:

```
_tile getTileAt(int index) {
  return *tile[index/Mh][index%Mh]; //mod returns the remainder
}
```

Comment: i just used "_tile *a = &tile[index/Mh][index%Mh]" instead of using a function.